# jquery mouseenter fires continuosly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mousenter/mouseleave function that swaps out content when the element is being hovered over. however instead of it firing only on mouseenter it seems to keep continuously firing. I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NCR4m/9/) so hopefully it will be easier to understand.

Comment: thanks for the seemingly-infinite loop heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `rotate_start()` and `rotate_reset()` functions you are triggering a hover event via this line:

```
jq('.product-image-container',super_prod).attr('hover','true');
```

Per JQuery docs, `hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You're basically applying recursion unintentionally, as `hover` is fired as the mouse moves.

A simple fix for this is to replace `.attr('hover','true');` with `.data('hover',true);`

Here is a scalable solution which should accomplish your objective:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Main product photo
        </li>
        <li>
            Alternate product photo 1
        </li>
        <li>
            Alternate product photo 2
        </li>
        <li>
            Alternate product photo 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #666;
}
.item ul li {
    display:none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var timers = [];
var interval_seconds = 2;

jq('.item').mouseenter(function() {

    // Scope this
    var _this = jq(this);

    // Self-executing function
    (function cycle() {

        // Recursive setTimeout accommodates for animation time - setInterval wont
        timers['item'] = setTimeout(function() {

            // Grab the currently visible photo, and the next photo
            var _this_li = _this.find('li:visible');
            var _next_li = _this_li.next();

            // If there is no next photo, cycle back to first photo
            if (_next_li.length == 0) {
                _next_li = _this.find('li:first-child');
            }

            // Animate the rotation
            _this_li.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                _next_li.fadeIn('slow', function() {

                    // Recursion
                    cycle();
                });
            });
        }, interval_seconds * 1000);
    })();
});

jq('.item').mouseleave(function() {

    // Stop the recursive setTimeout
    clearTimeout(timers['item']);

    // Scope this
    var _this = jq(this);

    // Grab the first photo in the list
    var _first_li = _this.find('li:first-child');

    // If the first photo in the list is not the currently visible photo, make it so.
    if (_first_li.not(':visible')) {
        _this.find('li:visible').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            _first_li.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});

jq(function() {

    // Show the first photo on load
    jq('.item').find('li:first-child').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/EY8mM/1/

Comment: i tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work. Im also a little confused how this is even invoking the hover function?

Comment: It's true, I was wrong - voted up this answer, I tried it in OP's fiddle and it seems accurate.

Comment: would this be a better way of setting up the function calls?      jq('.category-products .product-image-container').hover(
        function(){rotate_start(this);},
        function(){rotate_reset(this);}
        );

Comment: you're setting the "hover" pseudo-attribute which makes the object think you're hovering over it, which fires the mouseenter.  That then sets the hover attribute again and round and round you go.

Comment: No you'd be inadvertently doing the same thing. What's your ultimate objective here with the image swapping?

Comment: ultimately im going to rotate the content a few times while someone is hovering over the element

Comment: hmm ok give me a minute and i'll code up something better for you.

Comment: Thanks man thats exactly what i was looking for. Still a little confused as to why it wasn't working. The hover attribute issue makes sense but then im not sure why it wasn't working when i switched to the .data() method. I intend to use your solution which is better suited, but Im still curious as to why hover() was also being called. Thanks though this helps alot!

Comment: @alienwebguy that is one hell of a sexy jquery solution. perfect syntax and not over-engineered at all.